# How To Prepend Variable Pattern By Piping Grep Output To Sed?

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed, grep

I have the following data in two files:

`domains.txt` contains:

```
http://example1.com
```

`urls.txt` contains:

```
http://example1.com/url-example/
http://example5.com/url-example/
http://example2.com/url-example/
```

Using the following command (I'm using this structure because usually there is more in the files and this is just a minimal example):

```
cat domains.txt | while read LINE; do grep -m 1 "$LINE" urls.txt
```

This will give me the matching line.

```
http://example1.com/url-example/
```

However, I would like the desired output to be:

```
http://example1.com,http://example1.com/url-example/
```

I would like to add a pipe that would prepend the `"LINE"` variable before the matched output. I was thinking something with `sed` should be easy? Your input is highly appreciated.

Update:

Although this is easy with `awk`, if someone has an answer with piping the output, I would like to use that to go with the script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
while IFS= read -r line; do echo -n "$line,"; grep -m 1 "$line" urls.txt; done < domains.txt
```

Comment: Ah, I knew it was something simple like this. Thank you @Cyrus.

Answer (score 1):

This is very easy to do using awk:

```
while read LINE; do awk -v pattern="$LINE" '$0 ~ pattern { print pattern "," $0 }' urls.txt; done < domains.txt
```

Or using sed:

```
while read LINE; do sed -ne "s?$LINE.*?$LINE,&?p" urls.txt; done < domains.txt
```

To answer your follow-up question, to limit the result to the first match using awk:

```
while read LINE; do awk -v pattern="$LINE" '$0 ~ pattern { print pattern "," $0; exit }' urls.txt; done < domains.txt
```

Comment: Hey Janos, this isn't in the question, but could you limit the result to the first match?

Comment: Just to be clear...it wasn't me. Thanks for the follow up Janos.